# React Native, Flatlist customize with 2 item per row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I make my flatlist look like this? Is there any prop for this or which style I need to use to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can provide extra property `numColumns={2}` in your Flatlist component to get two items each row.

here is a wonderful tutorial by Spencer: https://www.reactnativeschool.com/react-native-flatlist-grid

Answer (score 4):

```
<FlatList
      numColumns={2}
     ....................
    />
```

Render your data and make `numColumns={2}`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the numColumns prop of the flat list which would display the items in columns

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns